# Annoying beep tone after Ubuntu 20.04 install on Macbook 5,1

Tags: boot, bootloader, boot-repair

I'm using an older macbook (5,1), to solely run Linux.  Everything is up and running, but on each startup I get a long monotone beep during a black screen.  Then it proceeds to its grey screen after a bit and sounds off with its Apple (Wall-E) welcome sound.  I've researched everything I can think of to solve this beep.  Its mostly just an annoyance since its rather loud.  I can only imagine its whatever is leftover from Apple's firmware that is competing with Grub to make that happen.  Also, without OSX, why is there even the Apple startup sound anyway?  I've looked and tried as many tricks as I could on here, and elsewhere with no success.
Attempted: PRAM/SVC reset, updating Grub, reverting to legacy Grub, complete re-installs, boot-repair, efibootmgr commands, etc...
I no longer have OSX to attempt any tricks through there, so I'm hoping there is a cure from the Ubuntu side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this support article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202768) it sounds like your machine may be trying to do an EFI ROM update. If it’s happening with every boot, there may be something failing. As for the welcome chime, that’s built into the ROM. There’s no erasing that without a MacOS update to something like Catalina.

Comment: That's definitely not encouraging.  I know its a long shot, but is there any way to flash the latest update from Linux?  I would rather not have to buy a version of OSX, install it, and then update the firmware just to confirm that its broken.

Comment: Flash a MacBook’s EFI within Linux? That’s not something I have ever done. Not sure it’s even possible. Depending on what version of OS X (or macOS) that notebook last ran, you may not need to buy the operating system. It’s been a free download from Apple for quite some time. If you want to go through the work of putting macOS on the device, [this page has a step-by-step](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5547136) that will help. It’s a lot of work to remove a noisy boot cycle, though 

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I'll give that a shot.